# VPS inodes at limit - which files should be removed/deleted to free up inodes

Tags: linux, centos, vps, inode

My VPS (CentOS 6.3.8.13 Parallels Plesk Panel)  has reached `inodes` limit:

```
[root@vps21157 tmp]# df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
rootfs               1507328 1507328       0  100% /
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /
devtmpfs              255333    2188  253145    1% /dev
tmpfs                 255448       1  255447    1% /dev/shm
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/var/named
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.rfc1912.zones
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/etc/rndc.key
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/usr/lib64/bind
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.iscdlv.key
/dev/root            1507328 1507328       0  100% /var/named/chroot/etc/named.root.key
```

To free up `inodes`:

- What files in my system can be removed or deleted?
- What services can I disable?
- Any other options?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage

Comment: I realize that in this case, it's obviously not the right answer, but this is the primary reason I prefer to use file systems that will dynamically allocate new inodes as necessary, rather than having a static table with a hard limit...

Answer (score 0):

You can check for directories using a lot of inodes with the following command:
for i in `ls -1a | grep -v "\.\./|\./"`; do echo "`find $i | sort -u | wc -l` $i"; done | sort -rn | head -10

deleting files in /proc won't really help you, the rest should.