# Couchbase: Approach full disk warning while still have a lot of free disk space

Tags: couchbase

We are using couchbase 3.0 and have around 67 GB free disk space, which is 35% free. But we face this warning this morning from the tab "Cluster Overview" in couchbase's admin page:

`Approaching full disk warning. Usage of disk "/" on node "local.node" is around 100%`

Even the admin page shows the correct Disk Overview: Usable Free Space (67.9 GB). But how come this warning appears?

Comment: Also I found the server doesn`t even start after it says that buckets are using all the disk space even though they are not.

Comment: Is it the same situation for every node of your cluster?

Comment: What platform is Couchbase running from? Is it Windows, Red Hat, Ubuntu,  Debian, SuSE, Oracle Linux? If it's Linux based, you could be experiencing an "inode are fully used" situation (inodes are used to store file information). If you have access to the terminal type in `df -ih` to show how much inodes are available, how much is used, and how much is free. If any of the drives is completely full, the best thing you can do is try to free up what is causing it to be full, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/653174/3206232