# Couchbase Approaching full disk warning on Mac OS X

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to install Couchbase Enterprise Edition in my Mac OS X. I have followed the instruction as mentioned [here](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/getting-started/installing.html). I have disabled replication and loaded sample data set `beer-sample` and `travel-sample`. But then I am getting the below warning:-

[image]

I have also seen this unanswered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982171/couchbase-approach-full-disk-warning-while-still-have-a-lot-of-free-disk-space).

I am having 53 GB free.

[image]

Environment:-

1. Mac OS X - 10.11.6
2. Couchbase Enterprise Edition 4.5.1

Comment: Delete some junk from your hard drive

Comment: I am having 53 GB free. Updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

For development purposes the warning is safe to ignore. I'm not sure why it's actually occurring given the amount of free space you have - it may be getting cached somewhere.

Comment: You mean couchbase caching?