# Running out of inodes on a docker volume

Tags: macos, docker, centos, docker-compose, inode

I have the following docker-compos.yml file:

```
 web:
   build: .
   ports:
     - "4200:4200"
     - "35729:35729"
   volumes:
     - ..:/code
     - ../home:/home/dev
```

which maps the 2 volumes above.  When I login into my VM and run `df -i` i see

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
none           1218224 509534 708690   42% /
tmpfs           256337     18 256319    1% /dev
shm             256337      1 256336    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           256337     11 256326    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none              1000      0   1000    0% /code
none              1000      0   1000    0% /home/dev
/dev/sda1      1218224 509534 708690   42% /etc/resolv.conf
/dev/sda1      1218224 509534 708690   42% /etc/hostname
/dev/sda1      1218224 509534 708690   42% /etc/hosts
tmpfs           256337     18 256319    1% /proc/kcore
tmpfs           256337     18 256319    1% /proc/timer_stats
```

As you can /code and /home/dev my 2 volumes only have 1000 inodes, so when I run my build process and it ends up creating a ton of files, I get an error that I don't have enough inodes.

Host = OSX
Guest = CentOs 6.5
Using Virtualbox

My question is: how do I assign more inodes to my data volumes /code and /home/dev above?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for a similar solution and so far, I've found this post to have some useful information in it:

- [how to free inode usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage)

Also, according to this post there doesn't seem to be a dynamic way of allocating inodes:

- [how can I increase the number of inodes ...](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem)

And finally, there is this line in the documentation:

- `it is not possible to expand the number of inodes on a filesystem after it is created`