# df -i and df-h , my server full weird issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have the following output when I use df-i

```
Filesystem                         Inodes    IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                        17465344 17400194     65150  100% /
none                              3085175        2   3085173    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                              3082347      440   3081907    1% /dev
tmpfs                             3085175      409   3084766    1% /run
```

Then when i df -h

```
root@Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal /var/www/html/manga # df -h
Filesystem                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3                        263G   67G  183G  27% /
none                             4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                              12G  4.0K   12G   1% /dev
tmpfs                            2.4G  644K  2.4G   1% /run
```

The problem is df -i , it return a 100% full which causes my apache2 &mysql unable restart or working well due to lack of disk space. any idea how do I increase my /dev/sda3 size on df -i because my df -h show that I only use 67% of the same place.

Thanks

Comment: You're not out of disk space, you're out of inodes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage

Comment: A common cause for this is old Kernel images. Consider `sudo apt-get autoremove` see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/317763/apt-get-no-space-left-on-device-12-04

Answer (score 3):

Your problem isn't related with python. Your filesystem is full of files, and the inodes are exhausted.

These questions are related with your problem: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26598/how-can-i-increase-the-number-of-inodes-in-an-ext4-filesystem and https://serverfault.com/questions/593298/how-to-increase-inodes.

I'm sorry for my English, a long time ago than I don't write in English.

This isn't a correct answer, probably a comment, but I'm not allowed to make comments.