# error: file write error: No space left on device

Tags: macos, github, operating-system, storage, space

I am attempting to update my git repo by doing "git add ." within Visual Studio Code on my MAC. I have done this many times without issues but this time it is giving me this error "error: file write error: No space left on device" and "error: unable to create temporary file: No space left on device." Also when trying to clone another repo onto my device from github it says "fatal: could not create work tree dir 'cs1550-project1-domm2': No space left on device" I have 12.96gb left of 256gb. I do not know how I am out of space or how to free it. I just need to update my github repo for class.

This is running df -h within the VS terminal:

```
df -h
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                                31G     0   31G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              6.2G  5.2M  6.2G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  196G   22G  165G  12% /
tmpfs                               31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                               31G     0   31G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          976M  310M  600M  35% /boot
/dev/loop0                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2253
/dev/loop2                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1270
/dev/loop1                          56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2284
/dev/loop3                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14295
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-lv_u        1.6T  1.6T     0 100% /u
/dev/loop6                          44M   44M     0 100% /snap/snapd/14549
/dev/loop5                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21835
/dev/loop4                          62M   62M     0 100% /snap/core20/1328
/dev/loop7                          68M   68M     0 100% /snap/lxd/21803
AFS                                2.0T     0  2.0T   0% /afs
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778380
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778801
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778557
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777582
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778716
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778813
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777367
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778536
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778347
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778708
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778462
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778799
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778330
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777512
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778756
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778555
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778783
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778747
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778712
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778329
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777696
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778494
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778816
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778752
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778706
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778823
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778556
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778766
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778343
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778828
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778538
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777510
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778809
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778353
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16777596
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778342
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778822
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778540
tmpfs                              6.2G     0  6.2G   0% /run/user/16778542
```

This is running it through my MAC terminal:

```
df -h
Filesystem       Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5s1  233Gi   14Gi   12Gi    55%  553788 2447547532    0%   /
devfs           196Ki  196Ki    0Bi   100%     679          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4    233Gi  3.0Gi   12Gi    21%       4 2448101316    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s2    233Gi  320Mi   12Gi     3%    1226 2448100094    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s6    233Gi   24Mi   12Gi     1%      17 2448101303    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s1    233Gi  203Gi   12Gi    95%  576260 2447525060    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home     0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home

df -i                 
Filesystem     512-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s5s1  489620264  29961272  24759664    55%  553788 2447547532    0%   /
devfs                 392       392         0   100%     679          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s4    489620264   6294912  24759664    21%       4 2448101316    0%   /System/Volumes/VM
/dev/disk1s2    489620264    654696  24759664     3%    1226 2448100094    0%   /System/Volumes/Preboot
/dev/disk1s6    489620264     49528  24759664     1%      17 2448101303    0%   /System/Volumes/Update
/dev/disk1s1    489620264 426413408  24759664    95%  576260 2447525060    0%   /System/Volumes/Data
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /System/Volumes/Data/home
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on where you are trying to do the `git add .`

As [mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/683532/7490):

> The /snap mounts come from using software packages installed with [Snap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snap_(package_manager)).
>
> These utilize [loop devices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device) and are usually not writable.
>
> You will get some sort of "No space on device" error when trying to write to any of these locations and that is represented in `df -h` as showing those mounts as 100% in use.

But in your case, assuming the repository is in `/dev/...`:

```
devfs                 392       392         0   100%     679          0  100%   /dev
```

That means you don't have enough inodes.
Look for files to delete:

```
for x in /* ; do echo $x ; find $x | wc -l ; done
```

The goal is to [free inode usage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/653096/6309) or [increase the number of inodes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26598/7490).